# HTML5 <audio> stream OSX Safari ERROR

Tags: javascript, html, macos, safari, audio-streaming

i have a standard HTML5 document width a audio-Tag sourced to a streaming-url.

```
<audio controls="controls" autostart="0" src="[URL:PORT]/;"></audio>


<script type="text/javascript">

    window.addEventListener("play", function(evt)
    {
        if(window.$_currentlyPlaying)
        {
            window.$_currentlyPlaying.pause();
        }
        window.$_currentlyPlaying = evt.target;

    }, true);

</script>
```

It works fine in Chrome, Firefox and mobile Safari, but Safari on OSX says:

> Blocked script execution in 'http://localhost/audiostream/' because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set.
>
> Sandboxing '[URL:PORT]' because it is using HTTP/0.9.
>
> Cancelled resource load from '[URL:PORT]' because it is using HTTP/0.9 and the document was loaded with a different HTTP version.
>
> Failed to load resource: Cancelled resource load from '[URL:PORT]' because it is using HTTP/0.9 and the document was loaded with a different HTTP version.

Anybody knows whats wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is obviously a problem exclusively at Safari 10

https://support.apple.com/de-de/HT207157